# pass smart pointers as a pointer of pointer to a function

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

I'm trying to pass a smart pointer as a parameter of a function which takes a pointer of a pointer. I was wondering if there is any proper solution for that.

```
foo(Class** input)
{
   // Do something
}

myClass = std::make_Unique<Class>();

foo(&myClass.get())
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Manipulating the pointer that a smart pointer manages sounds a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work, and it's a good thing that it doesn't.

There are roughly two reasons why you need to pass a `Foo**`. It could be a function that wants a 2D array (array of pointers to arrays), or the function has a `Foo*`as output (should have used a `Foo*&` then). In your case, it appears that you're dealing with the array case, since the argument is called `input`.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to call `T**` a 2D array. Array of pointers has a different memory layout than a 2D array, i.e. `T[N][M]`. The difference is quite substantial.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's actually a return value of the function foo. but I can't change the signature.

Comment: @Mohsen67 Why would you want to *pass* a pointer to a function that wants to *return* a pointer?

Comment: What else can I do? either pass a raw pointer or I thought it's better to use smart pointer

Comment: @Mohsen67: Well , _you_ are right, but the signature isn't right.

Comment: @Mohsen67 What are your responsibilities regarding the returned pointer? If you are it's owner and required to manage it (are you the one that has to `delete` it later?) you should use a smart pointer. But since you can't pass one directly to the function, use a temporary raw pointer and pass ownership to the smart pointer at the first opportunity. If you *aren't* responsible for the pointed object, then a raw pointer is the correct solution.

Comment: `Class` is a *house*. A *pointer* to a house is its street address. A *smart pointer* is a gadget that contains the address and can show it for you, and it will also blow up the house if the gadget is changed in any way or destroyed. A *pointer to a pointer* to a house is a page in a notebook where one can write an address. Now your function wants a page in a notebook where it can write an address of a house it would presumably build for you. Now why in the world would you build a house, write its address to a gadget, then blow the house up so that another address could be written to it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I should free it after I use it. S I'm both responsible to create and delete it.